# Failed to install Cargo Requests

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using a Oracle Linux 8.7 and trying to install [the Rust HTTP client API styled after awesome Python request](https://crates.io/crates/requests)

I add to `Cargo.toml`

```
requests = "0.0.30"
```

Followed by `cargo build` command

```
cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `security-framework = "^0.1.9"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 2.8.2, 2.8.1, 2.8.0, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `native-tls v0.1.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `native-tls = "^0.1"` of package `hyper-native-tls v0.2.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `hyper-native-tls = "^0.2"` of package `requests v0.0.30`
    ... which satisfies dependency `requests = "^0.0.30"` of package `project v0.1.0 (/home/opc/project)`
```

Also, tried to add these dependencies

```
[dependencies]
requests = "0.0.30"
native-tls = "0.2.11"
hyper-native-tls = "0.3.0"
security-framework = "^2.8.2"
```

But the same error is happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `0.1` versions of the [`security-framework`](https://crates.io/crates/security-framework/versions) crate have been yanked from crates.io. I don't know the details, but I assume it is because there was a security issue with these versions. That means that new projects can't download them any more, nor can you use crates that depend on any of the `0.1` versions of `security-framework`, like the very old version `0.1.*` of `native-tls` (5 years old). The `requests` crate has not been updated in six years. I'd therefore consider it abandoned. You should look for an alternative HTTP client crate, like the popular [`reqwest`](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest).